# Getting the ramdisk id of an amazon elastic cloud storage?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud, ramdisk

I ran ec2-describe-instances, on which i got the output as

```
INSTANCE    i-14305121  ami-bf1d8a8f    ec2-54-244-161-27.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com   ip-10-244-164-7.us-west-2.compute.internal  running internshipkey   0       t1.micro    2013-05-29T06:03:25+0000    us-west-2c  aki-fc37bacc            monitoring-disabled 54.244.161.27   10.244.164.7            ebs                 paravirtual xen pqhmg1369807405200  sg-dbd193eb default false
```

with the ramdisk id as empty? How do I get my ramdisk id? I need it to make an AMI from an existing snapshot in s3.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern, paravirtual AMIs don't use separate ramdisk images (ARIs). The real kernel and ramdisk are loaded from the boot disk.

When you register the EBS snapshot as a new AMI, specify a paravirtual kernel (AKI), but omit the ramdisk (ARI) specification.